# MKPolygon using Swift (Missing argument for parameter 'interiorPolygons' in call)

Tags: ios7, swift, ios8, mkpolygon

Fellow Devs,
I'm trying to implement a polygon overlay on a mapview as follows:

```
private func drawOverlayForObject(object: MyStruct) {
    if let coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = object.geometry?.coordinates {
        let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
        self.mapView.addOverlay(polygon)
    }
}
```

The following error is presented:

> Missing argument for parameter 'interiorPolygons' in call

According to the documentation:
[Apple Docu:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_14)

> Mutable Pointers
>
> When a function is declared as taking an UnsafeMutablePointer
> argument, it can accept any of the following:
>
> - nil, which is passed as a null pointer
> - An UnsafeMutablePointer value
> - An in-out expression whose operand is a stored lvalue of type Type, which is passed as the address of the lvalue
> - An in-out [Type] value, which is passed as a pointer to the start of the array, and lifetime-extended for the duration of the call

Now I think that my approach then would be correct, providing a [CLLocationCoordinate2D] array. Did anyone experience the same problem and found a workaround?

thanks
Ronny

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error you're getting is Swift's cryptic way of saying that it can't find a method which matches your parameters. If you did try passing the `interiorPolygons` parameter, you'd get an equally confusing:

> Extra argument 'interiorPolygons' in call

Your code is pretty close though; you just need a couple of minor changes. In the doc you reference, it says one of the things you can pass is:

> An in-out [Type] value, which is passed as a pointer to the start of
>   the array, and lifetime-extended for the duration of the call

So, it's looking for an [in-out parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_267). Which is done by passing `coordinates` prefixed with an `&`, like so:

```
MKPolygon(coordinates: &coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
```

But, in-out parameters can't be constants. From the docs:

> You can only pass a variable as the argument for an in-out parameter.
>   You cannot pass a constant or a literal value as the argument, because
>   constants and literals cannot be modified.

So, you need to define `coordinates` with a `var` first:

```
if var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = object.geometry?.coordinates
```

Which makes the entire function look like this:

```
private func drawOverlayForObject(object: MyStruct) {
    if var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = object.geometry?.coordinates {
        let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
        self.mapView.addOverlay(polygon)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code, at least in Swift 2.1, produces:
'&' used with non-inout argument of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>'

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci you'll get that error if `coordinates` is defined with a `let` and not a `var`. Since `let` makes `coordinates` immutable, it can't be used as an `inout` argument (Swift 2.1 still has a semi-cryptic error in this case).

Answer (score 0):

My final solution by cherry-picking from several tutorials and integrating:

```
func setPolylineFromPoints(locations:[CLLocation]){
    if locations.count == 0 {
        return;
    }
// while we create the route points, we will also be calculating the bounding box of our route
// so we can easily zoom in on it.
    var pt : UnsafeMutablePointer<MKMapPoint>? // Optional
    pt = UnsafeMutablePointer.alloc(locations.count)
    for idx in 0..<locations.count-1 {
       let location = locations[idx]
       let point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(location.coordinate);
       pt![idx] = point;
    }
    self.polyline = MKPolyline(points:pt!, count:locations.count-1)
// clear the memory allocated earlier for the points
    pt?.destroy()
    pt?.dealloc(locations.count)
}
```